# Distance from a point to a finite set of points

Tags: python-3.x, performance, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have three numpy arrays, let's say X, Y and Z.

X contains n arrays of dimension m, i.e. `[[x11,x12,...,x1m],[x21,x22,...,x2m],...,[xn1,xn2,...,xnm]]`

Y contains k (k > n) arrays of dimension m, i.e. `[[y11,y12,...,y1m],[y21,y22,...,y2m],...,[yk1,yk2,...,ykm]]`

Z contains p (p < k, p < n) arrays of dimension m, i.e. `[[z11,z12,...,z1m],[z21,z22,...,z2m],...,[zp1,zp2,...,zpm]]`

For each element Z[i] of the array Z, I need to compute the distance (euclidian) to every element of the array X and select the minimum distance, which will be denoted by dist_X[i]. I have to do the same but with the array Y and denote the minimum distance by dist_Y[i]. Then, for each element Z[i] of Z, I have to compute the value of dist_Y[i]/(dist_Y[i]+dist_X[i]).

I tried doing something like this:

```
import scipy
from scipy import spatial

def dist_sets(z):
    tree_X = spatial.cKDTree(X)
    tree_Y = spatial.cKDTree(Y)
    dist_X, minid_X=tree_X.query(z)
    dist_Y, minid_Y=tree_Y.query(z)
    return dist_Y/(dist_Y+dist_X)

print(dist_sets(Z))
```

However, it takes A LOT of computing time for large n,k and p; for example (n,m)=(17727, 122), (k,m)=(542273, 122) and (p,m)=(140001, 122).

Is there a way to optimize the code in Python, in such a way that I could evaluate the function dist_sets(Z) for all the elements of Z?

Comment: I don't think that cKDTree should give you a big speed up with 122 dimensions. Did you consider naive distance-matrix approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for KDTree mention that performance benefits deteriorate for larger dimensions. With 122 of them, you are probably better of with a naive vectorized solution. Here is one possibility:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances_argmin_min

def dist_sets2(Z):
  iX, dX = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(Z, X)
  iY, dY = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(Z, Y)
  return dY / (dX + dY)
```

For `k = p = 1000`, this is 17 times faster on my machine than using `cKDTree`.